# How can i make this Horror Voice?

Tags: voice, ableton-live, horror, sample

Can somebody tell me how i can make/produce this Horror Voice with Ableton Live or other programs.

Its an Horror Sample from an German Movie. This Voice means " dont touch me ".

You can download this Sample!

http://www.linkfile.de/download-27cda4b5a2118390de6130f52b961e28.php

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a female voice, pitch-adjusted upwards for a synth-y quality, with a little fuzz for a buzzy static edge, a drop of phase shift for shimmer, and a short but noticeable time delay to introduce a second copy of the voice. The recording itself may be doubled instead of a delay; it's so short and heavily processed it's hard to tell.